# display multiple rows of inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, underscore.js

I'm using underscore templates and backbone.  Pretty new to the web overall.  I'm displaying my data like this:

```
<% _.each(sources, function (source) { %>
                <div class="inline">
                    <%= source.name %>

                    <label class="dropdown inline">Library:
                        <select id="libraryPrepName" class="inline">
                            <% _.each(libraries, function (library) { %>
                            <option value="<%=library.id%>"><%= library.name %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                        </select>
                    </label>               
                <% }); %>
                // clearfix? <p> tags?
                </div>
```

I wasn't sure how to get each line on their own row.  I tried using bootstrap's clearfix class or a `<p>` tag to try to get a line break, but did not know the best way to do that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `</div>` is outside the each? Try moving it in.

Comment: As a side note, is there a special reason you use `<div class="inline">`? If not, you should probably use `<span>` elements...

Comment: @netrunner is it better to use span of inline for each item I want inline?

Comment: @TryingToImprove I moved the <div> inside the _.each and it still gave me the same results.  Everything is just on one line.

Comment: A `<span>` is an inline element by default, so in your case I'd say is the right choice.

Comment: You should probably aim at generating the html as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/CV44c/), with a `<div>` for each row and the elements on each row inside a `<span>`

Comment: @Crystal Try put the `</div>` and then the `clearfix` into the end of the outer loop, then it should have a newline for every div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
<% _.each(sources, function (source) { %>
    <div>
        <span>
            <%= source.name %>

            <label class="dropdown">Library:</label> 
            <select id="libraryPrepName">
                <% _.each(libraries, function (library) { %>
                    <option value="<%=library.id%>"><%= library.name %></option>
                <% }); %>
            </select>    
        </span>                 
    </div>                  
<% }); %>
```

Although I am not sure where do you want to position `<%= source.name %>` exactly...